# Include files via custom qmake function

Tags: qmake

I am new to the `qmake` and I'm experimenting with project structures.
I right now structured my project like

```
./src/
   logic/
   ui/
   controller/
   etc...
./inc/
   logic/
   ui/
   controller/
   etc...
```

I wanted to create a function that properly includes a new *.h and *.cpp file accordingly, so I did:

```
cont = "controller"
logic = "logic"
ui = "ui"

defineReplace(myFunction) {
    path = $$1
    name = $$2
    HEADERS *= ./inc/$${path}/$${name}.h
    SOURCES *= ./src/$${path}/$${name}.cpp
}

myFunction(cont,file1)
```

I expected the outcome to be as if I'd just put:

```
HEADERS *= ./inc/controller/file1.h
SOURCES *= ./src/controller/file1.cpp
```

But I just receive a `myFunction is not a recognized test function`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Qmake makes a difference between "replace"-functions (i.e. returning a string, like variable substitution in make; typically used on the rhs of assignment) and "test"-functions (returning a boolean value suitable for conditional operator).

`myFunction(cont, file)` is a call of a test function; `$$myFunction(cont, file)` is a call of a replace function.

Also note that Qmake file basically consists of assignments and conditions. Therefore, `myFunction(cont, file)` is interpreted as

```
myFunction(cont, file) {
    # nothing
} else {
    # nothing
}
```

Another problem is that functions in Qmake work with own private copy of variables, so you must use `export()` to make your changes visible outside. Hence, we have:

```
# replace function example code
defineReplace(myFunction) {
    HEADERS *= ./inc/$$1/$${2}.h
    SOURCES *= ./src/$$1/$${2}.cpp
    export(HEADERS)
    export(SOURCES)
    # warning: conditional must expand to exactly one word
    #return()
    # warning: conditional must expand to exactly one word
    #return(foo bar)
    # ok: any word will do as we don't care for true/false evaluation
    return(baz)
}

# test function example code
defineTest(myFunction) {
    HEADERS *= ./inc/$$1/$${2}.h
    SOURCES *= ./src/$$1/$${2}.cpp
    export(HEADERS)
    export(SOURCES)
    # warning: unexpected return value
    #return(foo)
    # ok: returns true
    #return(true)
    # ok: also returns true
    #return()
    # ...or simply return true by default
}

# calling replace function
$$myFunction(cont, file)
# calling test function
myFunction(cont, file)
```

Comment: A very, very late reply, thank you and "accepted"!!